# Why are TH elements missing from the DOM table API?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table, language-lawyer

I'm building HTML tables with the [DOM table API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), but I'm not sure how to create `th` elements using said API, and the more I dig the more it seems like I can't.

For example, given a *`table > thead > tr`* that has been set up like this:

```
let table = ...;                 // some HTMLTableElement
let thead = table.createTHead(); // a new HTMLTableSectionElement
let row = thead.insertRow();     // a new HTMLTableRowElement
```

If I do this, it inserts a `td`, not a `th`:

```
row.insertCell().textContent = 'something';
```

So, I have to do this instead:

```
let th = document.createElement('th');
th.textContent = 'something';
row.appendChild(th);
```

... which works fine (and is what I'm doing now), but doesn't use the table API, which seems weird.

So, I looked through the MDN docs as hard as I could but the `th` elements seem to be missing from the API entirely, and I'm not sure if that's on purpose, or if it's an oversight, or if `th`'s just aren't cool any more, or if they're there but I'm missing something:

- [*HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) specifically notes that it can't be used to insert a *th*.
- [*HTMLTableRowElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement) doesn't seem to have any other method for it (and also there's some broken links on that MDN page).
- [*HTMLTableSectionElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableSectionElement) doesn't have any special stuff for rows in a header.
- [*HTMLTableElement.createTHead()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/createTHead) just returns an *HTMLTableSectionElement*, not some `thead`-specific object with specialized methods for headers or whatever.
- Looking through the [index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API#interfaces), there doesn't appear to be anything that could be specific to a `th`, at least not in the vicinity of the other "HTMLTable..." things.

Even without `th`-specific API, I would have expected e.g. some behind-the-scenes magic that made the element returned by `createTHead().insertRow().insertCell()` be a `th` instead of a `td` or something.

So, the fact that the DOM table API seems to cover every single aspect of dealing with tables *except* for `th` makes me feel like I am missing something, and my questions are:

- Assuming I'm not missing anything, **what happened... ? Why is TH  (apparently) omitted from the API?**
- But, if I *am* misinterpreting, then, is there a way to create `th` elements with the table-specific API?

---

Here is an example snippet. The `createOneTable` function is some boilerplate table creation stuff, and its parameter is a function used to create header cells. It is set up like this to (hopefully) make the interesting parts clear. The stylesheet will set `th` backgrounds to yellow.

```js
// in the callbacks below:
//   header: an HTMLRowElement of a table>thead>tr
//   str: text to insert
//   postcondition: cell containing str appended to header

createOneTable((header, str) => {
  // this inserts a td
  header.insertCell().textContent = str;
});

createOneTable((header, str) => {
  // this just doesn't use the table api
  let cell = document.createElement('th');
  cell.textContent = str;
  header.appendChild(cell);
});

//---------------------------------------------

function createOneTable (addth) {

  const DATA = [
    [ 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Favorite Food' ],
    [ 'Jason', 'C', 'Rocks' ],
    [ 'Sam', 'Hamwich', 'Spiderwebs' ],
    [ 'Debbie', 'Downer', 'Pine cones' ]
  ];

  let table = document.createElement('table');

  // thead: create header row then populate
  let thead = table.createTHead();
  let header = thead.insertRow();
  for (let str of DATA[0])
    addth(header, str);

  // tbody: create content rows then populate
  let tbody = table.createTBody();
  for (let strs of DATA.slice(1)) {
    let row = tbody.insertRow();
    for (let str of strs)
      row.insertCell().textContent = str;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(table);

}

if (typeof(jQuery) !== 'undefined')
  throw Error("Weird, because I don't *see* a jquery tag on the question...");
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em; }
th,td { border: 1px solid black; }
th { background: yellow; }
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no "legal" way.

but You can do

```
row.insertCell().outerHTML = `<th> ${'something'} </th>` ;
```